# Tensorflow symmetric matrix

Tags: tensorflow, matrix

I want to create a symmetric matrix of `n*n` and train this matrix in TensorFlow. Effectively I should only train `(n+1)*n/2` parameters. How should I do this?

I saw some previous threads which suggest do the following:

```
X = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([d,d], minval=-.1, maxval=.1, dtype=tf.float64))

X_symm = 0.5 * (X + tf.transpose(X))
```

However, this means I have to train `n*n` variables, not `n*(n+1)/2` variables.

Even there is no function to achieve this, a patch of self-written code would help!

Thanks!

Comment: Using the answer from the other question doesn't mean you are training twice as many variables. There is still the same number of degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`tf.matrix_band_part(input, 0, -1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_band_part) to create an upper triangular matrix from a square one, so this code would allow you to *train* on `n(n+1)/2` variables although it has you *create* `n*n`:

```
X = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([d,d], minval=-.1, maxval=.1, dtype=tf.float64))
X_upper = tf.matrix_band_part(X, 0, -1)
X_symm = 0.5 * (X_upper + tf.transpose(X_upper))
```

Comment: How can you modify this to obtai na skew-symmetric matrix?

Comment: X_skew_ymm = 0.5 * (X_upper - tf.transpose(X_upper))

Answer (score 1):

Referring to answer of gdelab: in Tensorflow 2.x, you have to use following code.

```
X_upper = tf.linalg.band_part(X, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

gdelab's answer is correct and will work, since a neural network can adjust the 0.5 factor by itself. I aimed for a solution, where the neural network actually only has `(n+1)*n/2` output neurons. The following function transforms these into a symmetric matrix:

```
def create_symmetric_matrix(x,n):
    x_rev = tf.reverse(x[:, n:], [1])
    xc = tf.concat([x, x_rev], axis=1)
    x_res = tf.reshape(xc, [-1, n, n])
    x_upper_triangular = tf.linalg.band_part(x_res, 0, -1)
    x_lower_triangular = tf.linalg.set_diag( tf.transpose(x_upper_triangular, perm=[0, 2, 1]), tf.zeros([tf.shape(x)[0], n], dtype=tf.float32))
    return x_upper_triangular + x_lower_triangular
```

with `x` as a vector of rank `[batch,n*(n+1)/2]` and `n` as the rank of the output matrix.
The code is inspired by [tfp.math.fill_triangular](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/fill_triangular).